# Given an answer set program X how do you identify an answer set for X

Tags: answer-set-programming

How do you identify the answer sets for II if you know what the answer set program II looks like?

Here is the problem:

[image]

The answer is suppose to be 1 and 3.

Here is what I am thinking, starting with looking at number 1: Okay so we got loc(1,ted, house1), loc(1, jane, house2), move(1,ted, house1, house2) all in II, so far so good. Then we got loc(2, ted, house2) which is also in II. Finally we have loc(2, jane, house1) also which is also on the left side, so everything seems fine.

For number 3 I basically think of it the same way.

However, number 2 is not a correct answer and I don't really understand why. Is it because the order matters? For example we can see that for the answer set program II we first have loc(2,ted,house2) and then ¬ab(2, loc, jane), but for answer set number 2 it is in the opposite order.

How are you suppose to think about this?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others in the future.  We're less interested in questions about how to solve a specific exercise, as that's unlikely to be of use to others in the future.  I encourage you to think about a specific conceptual question that you're unclear on, that might be of interest to someone else in the future, and see if you can ask about that.

Comment: @D.W. Well I think that "Given an answer set program X how do you identify an answer set for X" is as general as it gets and what is wrong with using an example to understand it? The example I took is from an exam a few years which you can't copy paste the text from because it's a picture and I don't think it would help to search the question either way, trust me. I appreciate the feedback, but I would much more appreciate an answer to my question. :)